# Updating SQL table with file path

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have used a file upload PHP to get files from user input form to the correct path:

```
<form  method="post" action="form_action1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="attachment1">Add file(s)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="attachment1" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="attachment1">
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="attachment2" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="attachment2">
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="attachment3" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="attachment3">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">PDFs, Word Docs or images (PNG, JPG, etc.) Maximum 16 MB. </small>
 </div>
</form>
```

And the PHP script part that handles the `$_FILES`is:

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "jobs_usr1";
 $password = "XXXXXXXX";

try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=jobs_users", $username,    $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
            $job_name=$_POST['job_name'];
            $comments=$_POST['comments'];
            $attachment1=$_POST['attachment1'];
            $attachment2=$_POST['attachment2'];
            $attachment3=$_POST['attachment3'];
            $due_date=$_POST['due_date'];
            $requestor=$_POST['requestor'];
            $req_email=$_POST['req_email'];
            $property=$_POST['property'];
            }
if(isset($_FILES['attachment1'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['attachment1']['name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['attachment1']['size'];
  $file_tmp = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['attachment1']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['attachment1']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","doc","pdf");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG, PNG, PDF or DOC file.";
  }

  if ( ! $errors ) {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
}
```

The file uploads to the correct spot, but does NOT upload the path to the SQL table. I was told that my script needs a query refresh, but it eludes me.

Also, I have multiple file upload areas. Can I do an `array` at `if(isset($_FILES['MAYBE ARRAY'])){`?

Comment: The form doesn't send a `SUBMIT` in the `POST`.

Comment: There's no need for `x===false`. Just do `!x`. Somehow you have `!$errors` later in the code, but then you go and double-negate that, so the `else` block is *if not not errors*. Reversing those blocks and removing the negation makes code a lot more sane to follow.

Comment: your PHP code does not execute any SQL. You need an INSERT. Please look it up in the mysql manaul.

Comment: Indeed, you initialize a PDO db connection but never do anything with it.

Comment: Oh the pdo isn't needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was never answered but I did finally get the answer.

So here it is:

First - my form:

```
<form method="post" action="form_action1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="attachment1">Add file</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="attachment1" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="attachment1">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Then my php file to handle the input:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "jobs_usr1";
    $password = "XXXXXXX";

    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=jobs_users", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";

if(isset($_FILES['attachment1'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['attachment1']['name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['attachment1']['size'];
  $file_tmp = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['attachment1']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['attachment1']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","doc","pdf","docx","tif","tiff","zip","xls","xlsx","ppt","pptx","numbers");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a different file";
  }

  if ( ! $errors ) {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
     echo $file_name;
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `jobs_canjobs`(`attachment1`) VALUES ('$file_name')";

$conn->exec($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

So what I am doing here is saying `if(isset($_FILES['attachment1'])){` meaning that is there are files in the input, I assign the `$file_name`, then I used the `echo` and then placed the variable into my insert statement.

This worked for me.